# html Transform rotate 90 deg with div

Tags: html, css, css-transforms

I am adding several divs to make the last div in a parent div to appear on the right side of parent div but rotated 90 degrees. However my content is being pushed out of the div. Below is the code so far:

```
 <div style="width:20px; float: right; margin: 0; padding: 0;  ">
  <div style="margin: 5px 5px 5px 0; vertical-align:bottom;">
   <div style="transform: rotate(90deg); vertical-align: bottom;margin-bottom: 0;left:0; font-size: 8px; width: 56px ; height: 55px">
                        TESTING NOW
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: Can you create a test case on http://jsfiddle.net?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is your inner div is bigger than the outer div and sticking out over the edge. Then when you rotate the inner div, by default it's rotating about its centre, so the text that was on top rotates around to the right.

You can change the relative sizings and positioning to compensate. Alternatively you could apply a `transform-origin` to tell the browser to rotate about (for example) the top left corner instead:

```html
<div style="width:20px; float: right; margin: 0; padding: 0;  ">
  <div style="margin: 5px 5px 5px 0; vertical-align:bottom;">
    <div style="transform-origin: 0 0 0; transform: rotate(90deg); vertical-align: bottom;margin-bottom: 0;left:0; font-size: 8px; width: 56px ; height: 55px">
      TESTING NOW
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Or (as requested in your comment) you could align your text to the bottom of the div using `display: flex; align-items: flex-end` (note that in this example the div still overflows, which may or may not be an issue depending on the rest of your CSS).

```html
<div style="width:20px; float: right; margin: 0; padding: 0;  ">
  <div style="margin: 5px 5px 5px 0; vertical-align:bottom;">
    <div style="display: flex; align-items: flex-end; transform: rotate(90deg); vertical-align: bottom;margin-bottom: 0;left:0; font-size: 8px; width: 56px ; height: 55px">
      TESTING NOW
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, do you know how I can vertically align the text to appear at the bottom of the inner most div? the regular align won't change it. And I agree with your assessment about the sizing.

Comment: @Sue see updated answer - you can use `display: flex; align-items: flex-end` on the innermost div

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<div style="float: right; margin: 0; padding: 0;  ">
  <div style="width: 60px;">
     <div style="font-size: 8px; transform: rotate(90deg); margin-top: 26px;">
        TESTING NOW 
     </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

where "margin-top" of the innermost = (width of the parent - font size)/2

Comment: Thanks for the code. but the content of div is being pushed out still here is what I added to your code  <div style="float: right; margin: 0; padding: 0; width:20px;height: 100%; ">
                 <div style="width: 20px;background-color: lightgrey;height: 100%;">
                 <div style="font-size: 8px; transform: rotate(90deg);  width:55px;height: 100%;margin-top: 1px;">
                        TESTING now
                 </div>
                </div>
              </div>

Comment: Good if it works. But I would rather use what http://stackoverflow.com/users/1469259/cupawntae gave you as a solution: define the rotation center with 'transform-origin: 0'

Answer (score 0):

dont use `float: right;` in the parent DIV, that will push your innermost DIV out while rotating

instead, assign a 100% width to the outermost parent DIV, add a DIV element before the rotated one and assign in the width of the left side element you want and use float:right in the innermost

EDIT:

THis code should do what you want.. you can mess around with the widths to get what you want:

```
<div style="width:100%;  margin: 0; padding: 0;  ">
<div style="width:90%;  margin-right: 5px; padding: 0;  ">
</div>
<div style="float: right;transform: rotate(90deg); vertical-align: bottom;margin-bottom: 0;left:0; font-size: 8px; width: 56px ; height: 55px">TESTING NOW
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Abhay, but that pushes my div to the left side of the parent div for some reason

Answer (score 0):

I used the transform origin, I am posting my answer it could help someone else looking for it

```
 <div style="width:20px;height: 100%; float: left; margin: 0; padding: 0; background-color: lightgrey; ">
            <div style="margin: 5px 5px 5px 0;">
                <div style="transform: rotate(-90deg); font-size: 9px; width: 70px ; height: 55px;text-space: 5px; ">
                    Testing Testing
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```